# Can I style the background of a checkbox?

Tags: html, css

My forms have checkboxes and I would like to replace the normal arrow check with a colored background that shows when the box is checked. I am not very familiar with CSS. Is this something I could do with CSS. I don't want to use anything fancy like jQuery. Just looking for something really basic.

Marilou

Comment: Unfortunately due to the inflexible nature of styling form elements across browsers consistently, JavaScript is generally used to pass the check/unchecked status to form elements hidden away behind faux form elements (a `<div>` or similar) which are easier to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [this](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/style-web-forms-css/)